# How to for loop using different columns of data frame?

Tags: r, for-loop, r-portfolioanalytics

Basically I was working on a portfolio return problem. The stock return is like:

```
AMZN <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2)
BBY <- c(0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3)
TGT <- c(-0.1, -0.3, -0.2,-0.5)
df1 <- data.frame(AMZN, BBY, TGT)
date <- c("2000-01-01","2000-02-01", "2000-03-01", "2000-04-01")
date <-  as.Date(date, "%Y-%m-%d") 
df1 <- cbind(date, df1)
xts <- xts(df1[,-1], order.by=df1[,1])
```

I want to use `Return.portfolio(xts, weight)` to calculate portfolio return. So
The weight is like

```
w1 <- c(0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4)
w2 <- c(0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3)
w3 <- c(0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.4)
Weights <- data.frame(w1, w2, w3)
```

Since there are several groups of weights assigned, I need to get multiple portfolio return.
The code I tried is

```
for (i in colnames(Weights)){
     Return.portfolio(xts, (Weights[[i]]))
 }
```

Although R does not report any error, the only thing I got is a value which i is "w3".

Comment: Your for loop lacks where you store the results,eg `B`. Have a placeholder before the fore loop, Maintain your for-loop structure, but inside of it, use `B <- cbind(B,Return.portfolio(xts, (Weights[[i]]))`

Comment: @Onyambu So should I B <- NULL to "reserve" the place, and after the for-loop, print(B) to show the result?

Comment: yes. that is correct

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks! I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to initialize a `NULL` object first. Maybe something like this

```
Return<-NULL
for (i in 1:ncol(Weights)){
 Return<- cbind(Return, Return.portfolio(xts, (Weights[[i]])))
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  you mean to use `for (i in 1:ncol(Weights))`

Comment: Sorry I'm not so sure what do you mean by Return <- NULL. Is this return the xts or is it something else?

Comment: @ZhefuChen It is to ensure that the function `cbind` works. Before you begin the loop, you have to create a placeholder variable where you will need to store your results from the loop.

Comment: @ZhefuChen this answer is not correct. It requires editing. Also its not because of 1:ncol... but rather the storing part. You could use your for-loop structure with a storing and it will still work

Comment: @Onyambu I'm not sure why but in my Rstudio this answer works and I only changed the names of the data frame.

Comment: @ZhefuChen: since the answer worked for you, could you please accept the answer?

Comment: @ssaha Sure. Sorry I'm new to Stack Overflow I didn't know I can accept an answer